# Media Buttons/Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this project and I have everything completed besides three java script buttons. (yes I have to use java script)

The buttons appear but when clicking on them they do nothing. I think the event listener isn't working for these. Any help sorting this out would be appreciated.

I've included all the necessary code in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/L5r3swbe/

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // Video
  var video = document.getElementById("video");

  // Buttons
  var playButton = document.getElementById("playPause");
  var muteButton = document.getElementById("mute");
  var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen");

  // Sliders
  var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
  var volumeBar = document.getElementById("volume-bar");

}

// Event listener for the play/pause button
//playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("playPause").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.paused == true) {
    // Play the video
    video.play();

    // Update the button text to 'Pause'
    playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    // Pause the video
    video.pause();

    // Update the button text to 'Play'
    playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
});

// Event listener for the mute button
muteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.muted == false) {
    // Mute the video
    video.muted = true;

    // Update the button text
    muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute";
  } else {
    // Unmute the video
    video.muted = false;

    // Update the button text
    muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute";
  }
});

// Event listener for the seek bar
seekBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // Calculate the new time
  var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

  // Update the video time
  video.currentTime = time;
});

// Update the seek bar as the video plays
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  // Calculate the slider value
  var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

  // Update the slider value
  seekBar.value = value;
});

// Pause the video when the slider handle is being dragged
seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  video.pause();
});

// Play the video when the slider handle is dropped
seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  video.play();
});

// Event listener for the volume bar
volumeBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // Update the video volume
  video.volume = volumeBar.value;
});
```

```css
/* body { padding-top: 70px; } */



h1 { font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0;}

div#topHeaderRow {


   font-size: 0.9em;
 
   /*
   height: 2em;
   background-color: yellow;  
   line-height: 2em;
*/
}

.price { font-size: 1.4em; color: red; font-weight: bold;}

.similarTitle { font-weight: bold; font-size: 0.9em; }

.cartText { font-size: 0.75em; }

footer {
   margin-top: 1em;
   background-color: #E7E7E7;

}

.tight-form-group { margin-bottom: 5px; }

#copyrightRow { background-color: #3A3A3A; padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0; margin-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chapter 7</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="Lab6.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/Lab6.js"></script>
   
    
  </head>

  <body>

<header>

   <div id="topHeaderRow" >
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse " role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <p class="navbar-text">Welcome to <strong>Art Store</strong>, <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Login</a> or <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Create new account</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse pull-right">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> Wish List</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Shopping Cart</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Checkout</a></li>                  
               </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>
      </div>
   </div>   
   
   <div id="logoRow" >
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1>Art Store</h1> 
            </div>
            

            <div class="col-md-4">
               <form class="form-inline" role="search">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                  </span>
               </div>
               </form> 
            </div>

                        
         </div>
     
      
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div id="mainNavigationRow" >
      <div class="container">

         <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Art Works</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Specials <b class="caret"></b></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Special 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Special 2</a></li>                   
                 </ul>
               </li>
             </ul>              
            </div>
         </nav>
      </div>  <!-- end container -->
   </div>  <!-- end mainNavigationRow -->
   
</header>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-9">
         <h2>Video How Tos</h2>
         <p>Sample video</p>


<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

<video controls poster="images/art/preview.png" id="video">
  <source src="images/art/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="images/art/sample.ogv" type="video/ogv">
  <source src="images/art/sample.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<!-- Video Controls -->
  <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="playPause">Play</button>
   <!-- <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0"> -->
    <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button>
    <!--<input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1"> -->
    <button type="button" id="full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>         
         
         

      </div>  <!-- end col-md-10 (main content) -->
      
      <div class="col-md-3">
    
      
         <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h3 class="panel-title">Other Videos</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                  <li><a href="#">Working with the cart</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Registering an account</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Checking out</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Using the search</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Checking your order</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Returning your order</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>  

         <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h3 class="panel-title">Problems Playing Videos?</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                  <li><a href="#">Download more recent browser</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Install Flash</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div> 
      
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 (right navigation) -->           
   </div>  <!-- end main row --> 
</div>  <!-- end container -->




    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bind the event handlers from inside your `window.onload` function. Your current code tries to reference variables that are local to that function from outside that function, and tries to bind handlers to elements that haven't been parsed yet. (If you check the dev console after running your existing code you should see errors.)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I failed to mention im a beginner. Can you point out or point me to how id properly do this?

Comment: There is a closing `}` on about line 15 that is the end of the `window.onload` function. Move that `}` to the end of the script. That will put the rest of the JS inside the `window.onload` function.

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thank you soooooo much. That worked great

Answer (score 2):

The variables you declared in your window.load handler is not accessible outside that function.
The easiest solution would be to put all the rest of the code in the window.load handler.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I failed to mention im a beginner. Can you point out or point me to how id properly do this?